# how to fix java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError crash

Tags: java, android, facebook, noclassdeffounderror, account-kit

My app is live on play store. Its not crashing in all devices but I can see this crash in a few device only. Please help me to fix this issue.

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Lcom/google/android/gms/auth/api/phone/SmsRetriever; at
>   com.facebook.accountkit.internal.PhoneLoginController.createSmsToken(PhoneLoginController.java:250)
>   at
>   com.facebook.accountkit.internal.PhoneLoginController.logIn(PhoneLoginController.java:188)
>   at
>   com.facebook.accountkit.internal.LoginManager.logInWithPhoneNumber(LoginManager.java:372)
>   at
>   com.facebook.accountkit.internal.AccountKitController.logInWithPhoneNumber(AccountKitController.java:627)
>   at
>   com.facebook.accountkit.ui.PhoneLoginFlowManager.logInWithPhoneNumber(PhoneLoginFlowManager.java:57)
>   at
>   com.facebook.accountkit.ui.ActivityPhoneHandler.onPhoneLoginComplete(ActivityPhoneHandler.java:189)
>   at
>   com.facebook.accountkit.ui.AccountKitActivity$1.onReceive(AccountKitActivity.java:176)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.executePendingBroadcasts(LocalBroadcastManager.java:297)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.access$000(LocalBroadcastManager.java:46)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager$1.handleMessage(LocalBroadcastManager.java:116)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) Caused
>   by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.google.android.gms.auth.api.phone.SmsRetriever" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/gharkadabba.gharkadabba-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/gharkadabba.gharkadabba-1/lib/x86,
>   /vendor/lib, /system/lib]] at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469) at
>   com.facebook.accountkit.internal.PhoneLoginController.createSmsToken(PhoneLoginController.java:250) 
>   at
>   com.facebook.accountkit.internal.PhoneLoginController.logIn(PhoneLoginController.java:188) 
>   at
>   com.facebook.accountkit.internal.LoginManager.logInWithPhoneNumber(LoginManager.java:372) 
>   at
>   com.facebook.accountkit.internal.AccountKitController.logInWithPhoneNumber(AccountKitController.java:627) 
>   at
>   com.facebook.accountkit.ui.PhoneLoginFlowManager.logInWithPhoneNumber(PhoneLoginFlowManager.java:57) 
>   at
>   com.facebook.accountkit.ui.ActivityPhoneHandler.onPhoneLoginComplete(ActivityPhoneHandler.java:189) 
>   at
>   com.facebook.accountkit.ui.AccountKitActivity$1.onReceive(AccountKitActivity.java:176) 
>   at
>   android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.executePendingBroadcasts(LocalBroadcastManager.java:297) 
>   at
>   android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.access$000(LocalBroadcastManager.java:46) 
>   at
>   android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager$1.handleMessage(LocalBroadcastManager.java:116) 
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
>   Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.google.android.gms.auth.api.phone.SmsRetriever at
>   java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781) at
>   java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
>                                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using
>   the boot class loader; no stack trace available

I can see Moto G (3rd & 4th Gen), One Plus one device having crash.

I added below line to ProGuard file.

> -ignorewarnings
>   -keep class * { public private *; }

Comment: What is the class that is not found? It is missing from the exception...

Comment: add your pro-guard configuration file

Comment: @NileshDeokar. updated with pro-guard file code.

Comment: Is there a possibility that a particular class doesn't exist in such devices?
How about using reflection?

Comment: No thats not possible. @Swati. its android 6/7. these are latest android versions.

If i add this to gradle. then only it crashing.
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'

Answer (score 1):

SMS Retriever API is available in Google Play Services v10.2 and is used to auto-verify the OTP SMS.

https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/

This API will not be available in the devices that do not have Google Play Services installed - like Amazon Fire devices or the devices in the Chinese region.

If you are using this API, you have to check whether Play services are installed in the device before accessing this API.

Looking at your exception, it seems this API has been used by some Facebook kit.

Comment: Yes, exception happen by Facebook Account kit.

Comment: You can check the crash report and confirm whether these crashes happen only in the devices that don't have Play services v10.2